# Attach onDoubleTapListener to a text view

Tags: java, android, textview

Okay, so I've been stuck for a couple of days now working with gestures within my app. All it is, is a basic stopWatch application and also a count down application it uses swipeable views to swap between the 2 different activities.

My problem is in my first fragment for the stopWatch part of the app I use a runnable to create and start the timer which works fine and it is currently set up so if the user taps on the timer Text view, it'll start the runnable and the timer will begin counting up. However the way I have set it up it can only accept one input method which is a single tap. This is where the gestures come in. I want to be able to single click to start the timer, double tap to pause the timer and a long press to stop and clear the timer Text view.

I've tried attaching a gesture detector to just the TextView but anything I try doesn't seem to work, I believe I can set the fragment up so if I were to click anywhere on the screen it would do what I wish but I don't want it to work like that. I want it to only work when the user clicks the timer Text view. I've come to a point where I thought I could get it to work, but that involves putting an onDoubleTapListener to my TextView, but for some reason I cannot do that, so does anyone have a way to do that or a way for my code to work?

Sorry for the long explanation but I figure the more information there is on what I want, the easier it would be for someone to help :)

Below is my code, I know it doesn't look too organised (Thats something I'm trying to work on) but hopefully you can see where I'm going wrong. Thanks!

(Also I know some of the views aren't used at all at the moment purely because I'm trying to get it working one step at a time :P also the part of commented out code, is the current way I'm running the timer I thought I'd leave it in here in case someone is wondering how I am currently starting the timer.)

```
package com.leccles.swipetabs;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.GestureDetectorCompat;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * A simple {@link android.support.v4.app.Fragment} subclass.
 * 
 */
public class FragmentA extends Fragment implements
    GestureDetector.OnGestureListener, GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener {
Button lapButton;
TextView timerText;
ListView lapListView;
TextView mMilliTextView;
String milliText;
long startTime = 0;
long timeInMilliSeconds = 0;
GestureDetectorCompat gDetector;

Handler timerHandler = new Handler();
Runnable timerRunnable = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        long millis = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
        int seconds = (int) (millis / 1000);
        int minutes = seconds / 60;
        seconds = seconds % 60;

        timerText.setText(String.format("%d:%02d", minutes, seconds));
        timerHandler.postDelayed(this, 500);
    }

};

public FragmentA() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    mMilliTextView = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.milliTextView);
    lapButton = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.lapButton);
    timerText = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.timerText);
    lapListView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.lapListView);

    this.gDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(getActivity(), this);

    timerText.setOnDoubleTapListener(this);

    /*
     * timerText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     * 
     * @Override public void onClick(View v) { TextView timerText =
     * (TextView) v; if (timerText.getText().equals(
     * getView().findViewById(R.string.stopWatchTime))) {
     * timerHandler.removeCallbacks(timerRunnable);
     * 
     * } else {
     * 
     * startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
     * timerHandler.postDelayed(timerRunnable, 0);
     * 
     * }
     * 
     * }
     * 
     * });
     */
}

@Override
public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX,
        float distanceY) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
        float velocityY) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem it was so simple. I didn't need to use an onDoubleTapListener. A simple onTouchListener worked(I had previously tried and failed at using this) I was trying to use it wrong. I didn't put the Gesture Detector into the on touch so it wouldn't ever work. Here is the working code below with the onTouchListener. I also didn't change the boolean in onTouch to true to state that the touch had been handled.

```
package com.leccles.swipetabs;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.GestureDetectorCompat;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * A simple {@link android.support.v4.app.Fragment} subclass.
 * 
 */
public class FragmentA extends Fragment implements
    GestureDetector.OnGestureListener, GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener {
Button lapButton;
TextView timerText;
ListView lapListView;
TextView mMilliTextView;
String milliText;
long startTime = 0;
String sPauseTime;
long iPauseTime;
long timeInMilliSeconds = 0;
GestureDetectorCompat gDetector;

Handler timerHandler = new Handler();
Runnable pauseRunnable = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        long millis = System.currentTimeMillis() + startTime;
        int seconds = (int) (millis / 1000);
        int minutes = seconds / 60;
        seconds = seconds % 60;

        timerText.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds));
        timerHandler.postDelayed(this, 500);

    }
};

Runnable timerRunnable = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        long millis = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
        int seconds = (int) (millis / 1000);
        int minutes = seconds / 60;
        seconds = seconds % 60;

        timerText.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds));
        timerHandler.postDelayed(this, 500);
    }

};

public FragmentA() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    mMilliTextView = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.milliTextView);
    lapButton = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.lapButton);
    timerText = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.timerText);
    lapListView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.lapListView);

    this.gDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(getActivity(), this);

    timerText.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            gDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            return true;
        }
    });

    /*
     * timerText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     * 
     * @Override public void onClick(View v) { TextView timerText =
     * (TextView) v; if (timerText.getText().equals(
     * getView().findViewById(R.string.stopWatchTime))) {
     * timerHandler.removeCallbacks(timerRunnable);
     * 
     * } else {
     * 
     * startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
     * timerHandler.postDelayed(timerRunnable, 0);
     * 
     * }
     * 
     * }
     * 
     * });
     */
}

@Override
public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
    sPauseTime = timerText.getText().toString();
    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    timerHandler.postDelayed(timerRunnable, 0);

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
    sPauseTime = timerText.getText().toString();
    timerHandler.removeCallbacks(timerRunnable);

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX,
        float distanceY) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
    timerHandler.removeCallbacks(timerRunnable);
    timerText.setText("00:00");

}

@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
        float velocityY) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);
}
```

}